# Remove NaN and convert to float32 in Python Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am reading in data from a csv file into a data frame, trying to remove all rows that contain NaNs and then convert it from float64 to float32. I have tried various solutions I've found online, nothing seems to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you want instead of the NaNs?

Comment: Good comment, let me edit the question

Comment: But won't the dtype be float anyway if it has `NaN`?

Comment: What I want to do is float64 to float32 conversion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
pd.read_csv('Filename.csv').dropna().astype(np.float32)
```

To keep rows that only have *some* NaN values, do this:

```
pd.read_csv('Filename.csv').dropna(how='all').astype(np.float32)
```

To replace each NaN with a number instead of dropping rows, do this:

```
pd.read_csv('Filename.csv').fillna(1e6).astype(np.float32)
```

(I replaced NaN with 1,000,000 just as an example.)

Answer (score 4):

You can also specify the `dtype` when you read the csv file:

> dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type
>         Data type for data or columns. E.g. {'a': np.float64, 'b': np.int32}

```
pd.read_csv(my_file, dtype={col: np.float32 for col in ['col_1', 'col_2']})
```

Example:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([5,5]), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df_out.iat[1,0] = np.nan 
df_out.iat[2,1] = np.nan
df_out.to_csv('my_file.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', dtype={col: np.float32 for col in list('ABCDE')})
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Unnamed: 0    5 non-null int64
A             4 non-null float32
B             4 non-null float32
C             5 non-null float32
D             5 non-null float32
E             5 non-null float32
dtypes: float32(5), int64(1)
memory usage: 180.0 bytes

>>> df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
   Unnamed: 0         A         B         C         D         E
0           0  0.176224  0.943918  0.322430  0.759862  0.028605
3           3  0.723643  0.105813  0.884290  0.589643  0.913065
4           4  0.654378  0.400152  0.763818  0.416423  0.847861
```